# how java function description works in eclipse code suggestion

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, javadoc

When we are using eclipse , it gives suggestions for our java code and shows description i.e a small pop over showing description about the function . Suppose i am creating a java library and i need to add these description about functions in my library that should be recognized by eclipse and show as suggestion , how should i specify the description i.e what kind or format of annotations i need to use to show these description about functions .
can anybody provide me links for the solution of the above .

Comment: you should have googled it at least once. Simple enough to find.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi it is funny but i googled it and here i am. i think nothing is wrong here.

Answer (score 8):

All you need to provide is `javadoc`.

Before the begining of the method mention comments like

```
/**
 ...
*/
```

and you should be done.

Here are couple of links to help you...

[Javadoc Tutorial](http://www.mcs.csueastbay.edu/~billard/se/cs3340/ex7/javadoctutorial.html)

[How to write Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html)